# XCode Library search path

Tags: xcode, macos

For my iOS project, I have a specific folder structure:

```
|-- root    
|     |-- src
|     |  |-- xcode                            
|     |     |-- MyProject
|     |        |-- <sources>, ...
|     |     |-- MyProject.xcodeproj
|-- library
```

In build settings, I would like to add Library Search Path that points to "library", which is on the same level as "root" directory. When I put `$(SRCROOT)`, search path correctly points to `root/src/xcode` directory. However, I do not know how to look for library two folders "above" the src of the project.
I have tried with
"../../$(SRCROOT)" but with no effect.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it's `$(SRCROOT)/../../../library` (I'm not sure whether it needs trailing slash)

`$(SRCROOT)/..` points to `root/src` (one level up from `root/src/xcode`)

`$(SRCROOT)/../..` points to `root`(two levels up from `root/src/xcode`)

`$(SRCROOT)/../../../library` points to `library`

Comment: Wouldn't the last be `/library` insead of `root/library`?

Comment: $(SRCROOT)/../.. = root/src/xcode/../.. = root/src/.. = root, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, then it should be `$(SRCROOT)/../../../library` (or `/library`).

Comment: ah, right, I misread library being in root, not at the same level. Edited.