# How to convert/create a dicom image from jpeg using Imebra library?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, dicom

I want to create of convert a jpeg image to a dicom image using imebra library on iOS platform. In the objective c examples of the library the steps to convert or read a dicom into jpeg are given, however, I am going through the documentation and trying to achieve vice versa (i.e. jpeg to dicom). I have no background of c++ so any help would be appreciated. Links to the library and documentation:

1.https://imebra.com

2.https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/imebra_build_2013-10-30_10-00-11/html/dicom2jpeg_2dicom2jpeg_8cpp-example.html

Some basic code below, thanks in advance.

```
-(void)createDcmFromJpg
{

     NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test2" ofType:@"jpeg"];

    //Create read stream
    using namespace puntoexe;
    ptr<stream> readStream(new stream);
    readStream->openFile(NSStringToStringW(imagePath), std::ios::in);

   //create dataset
    ptr<streamReader> reader(new streamReader(readStream));
    ptr<imebra::dataSet> testDataSet = imebra::codecs::codecFactory::getCodecFactory()->load(reader);

    //set Tags
    testDataSet->setString(0x0010, 0, 0x0010, 0, "testStr");
    testDataSet->setString(0x0010, 0, 0x0010, 1, "testStr1");

   //Next step/steps ?
}
```

Comment: hi @Rohit Kashyap can you post your answer ?

Comment: Hi Deepak, the answer below by Paolo solved my problem.

Comment: hey rohit one more thing,  
after cmake build i get libimebra.a and also i add this lib into my project but when i import or include imebra/imebra.h , can't found imebra/imebra.h

Comment: Seems like a library or a header search path issue, go to the build settings and check the paths you have mentioned, make sure they are correct.

Comment: ya rohit you are right, but i don't understand which path are set to library and header search path ?

Comment: Wherever you have added the imebra library in your project folder, add that path, for example" projectdir/ExternalLibs/build". Example link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309434/xcode-library-search-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imebra::dataSet represents a collection of Dicom tags.

When you read a file (jpeg or dicom), then Imebra creates a dataSet which is a set of Dicom tags.

When reading a Dicom file then the dataSet will mirror exactly the tags stored in the Dicom file, while when reading a jpeg image Imebra will create a dataSet containing the proper dicom tag that embeds the jpeg image: all the needed Dicom tags will be already in the dataSet and you can add your own (like patient name, etc).

The next step consists in saving the dataSet to a Dicom stream:

with Imebra V4 (current):

```
// Load jpeg
std::unique_ptr<imebra::Dataset> testDataset(imebra::CodecFactory::load("/path/to/jpegfile.jpg"));

// Save as Dicom
imebra::CodecFactory::save(testDataset, "/path/to/file.dcm", imebra::codecType_t::dicom);
```

with Imebra 2015 (legacy):

```
// Open the Dicom file for writing
ptr<stream> writeStream(new stream);
writeStream->openFile(NSStringToStringW(dicomfilepath), std::ios::out);

// Declare the writer (will take care of writing into the stream)
ptr<streamWriter> writer (new streamWriter(writeStream));

// Use the dicom codec to write the dataSet into the file
ptr<imebra::codecs::codec> dicomCodec(new imebra::codecs::dicomCodec);
dicomCodec->write(writer, testDataSet);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paolo.